# handle json request in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, request, mime-types

When making an ajax call, when contentType is set to application/json instead of the default x-www-form-urlencoded, server side (in PHP) can't get the post parameters.
in the following working example, if I set the contentType to "application/json" in the ajax request, PHP $_POST would be empty.  why does this happen? How can I handle a request where contentType is application/json properly in PHP?

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxx.php",
    //contentType: "application/json",
    processData: true,
    data: {my_params:123},
    success: function(res) {},
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, text_status) {}
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<?php
   var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will find unrecognised MIME types in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. You can also force PHP to always populate this array (not only for unrecognised MIME types) by setting the php.ini directive `always_populate_raw_post_data` to true.

Raw post data will otherwise be available through the input wrapper `php://input`

For more information:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Answer (score 1):

above is technically correct, but since I don't write much PHP, this might be more helpful

xxx.php would be

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","a");
$post_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$post = json_decode($post_json, true);
foreach($post as $key=>$value) {
    $message = $key . ":" . $value . "\n";
    echo fwrite($file,$message);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

and then you can test with

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"fieldA":"xyz","fieldN":"xyz"}' http://localhost/xxx.php
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have phalcon extension you can use `getJsonRawBody ()`

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html