# $_POST variable is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I created a ajax request in Javascript using json, but the $_POST variable is empty.

```
var userid = "james";
var score = 200; 
var jsondata = {
userid: userid,
score: score
};
data = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
req = new XMLHttpRequest();   
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.open("POST", 'functions.php', true);
req.send(data);
```

My functions.php file looks like this:

```
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

However all of this gives me an empty array. Any help, please?

Comment: Try providing a key name with the data -- `var data = "name=james";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending data incorrectly,

Use,

```
req.send("name=James");
```

Comment: What about with JSON. My data is really JSON.

    var jsondata = {
    "userid": userid,
    "score": score
};

    data = JSON.stringify(jsondata); 
    req.send(data); 

Is this correct, please?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But It's still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user99615 Please update your question to reflect what exactly you are doing. This will help you get an accurate answer.

Comment: updated. Please do you have a clue why _POST variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` only gets populated for form encoded and multipart encoded data. Your data is encoded as JSON and should be accessed through `php://input` (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063787/handle-json-request-in-php)).

`$data` should contain the JSON. If it doesn't, then it is probably due to you failing to set the Content-Type header of the *request*.

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"). I also tried req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); but php://input still shows an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Except that the line `req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` should be under `req.open("POST", 'functions.php', true);`because the state of the XHR object must be open to set a header, your code is perfectly operational.

Your problem is somewhere else.

- How do you check what is your php displaying ?
- Is your ini conf. appropriate ? Try to do `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);` before `file_get_contents('php://input');`
- Check the paramter post_max_size in your php.ini. it should be 8M or 10M (no MB but M and only M, or php will interpete it as 0)

The best way to check the interpreted parameters of php.ini is to do an empty .php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and launch it; Then check the section "Core".

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I used file_get_contents('php://input') and I finally got my json results. Thanks!